# How do I pull an image from a webpage in node js?

Tags: node.js, image, request, discord.js, urlimageviewhelper

I'm currently trying to pull an image url from a website, and have that image url put in my code if that makes any sense.

Essentially, the request to the page goes through, and I need my code to grab an image on the page (the url of the image on the page), so it can send to a discord webhook.

What's the best way of doing this in node js? If this isn't enough information, please feel free to let me know and I will try my best to expand on this! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a little code that you have try so that we can help you

Comment: I think you can use `node-fetch`, but I’m not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have only put your question and no code/situation, I'll just elaborate on how you can get it in general.

- **Page is Dynamic**
  What I mean by that is like, your page has content which you want to fetch and that content is loaded by JavaScript. Then you could try using Headless libraries like [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) and [Nightmare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare). Note that, all of these packages are kinda heavy, for example, Puppeteer installs Chromium *(Not the Element, the Browser! If you don't know about it, read [this](https://www.lifewire.com/chromium-web-browser-4171288))* and Nightmare works with Electron *(Again not the chemistry one, it is an NPM Package)*
  You can leverage the built-in functions in there to get the element which you want. However, you will need to do a lot of Inspect Element stuff to get the exact element you want!
- **Page is Static**
  What I mean by Static is that all of the stuff you need is in the default HTML yourself! So you won't need headless browsers for that. *That's some heavy dependencies less for you*. 
  So what you will want to do is, fetch the site using packages like [Node-Fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). I know it is possible to do it with the core Node.js Module called [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) but it is waaaaaay too much of a hassle to use and is not really that suggested. 
  On your request, you will get the Raw HTML of the site (looks kinda trash ngl). So now what you will need to do with this Raw HTML is to PARSE it to get your Image URL! You can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) and [JSDom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to load your HTML and then parse the document to get the Image URL you want. *Both are pretty awesome ngl.*